# Is it possible to use 2 coding languages(python and C-language) to make a single program?

Tags: c, python-2.7

I've seen other programs use python scripts, and I was wondering if I could so in C. And why would these programs use python scripts instead of implementing what the python script would do in the actual program code? Thanks for answering.

Comment: Look up the terms "embedding" and "extending" in relation to scripting languages.

Comment: *And why would these programs use python scripts instead of implementing what the python script would do in the actual program code?* because python is much easier to learn than c

Answer (score 1):

Taking a look at [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html), the answer is yes.

> The simplest form of embedding Python is the use of the very high
>   level interface. This interface is intended to execute a Python script
>   without needing to interact with the application directly. This can
>   for example be used to perform some operation on a file.

```
#include <Python.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);  /* optional but recommended */
  Py_Initialize();
  PyRun_SimpleString("from time import time,ctime\n"
                     "print 'Today is',ctime(time())\n");
  Py_Finalize();
  return 0;
}
```

The reason behind using a python script instead of directly implementing it in C is because python is much more high-level and thus easier and faster to create (for the price of performance).

Comment: Thank you, especially for elaborating, I like long answers better than short ones

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. BTW, I suggest using some Python 3.4 (since 2.7 is really old, use it only for legacy code).

It is called [extending Python (with C code)](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/index.html) (you'll make a shared library -by compiling your C code- or "plugin" loadable by Python). You might also do the converse: embed a Python interpreter in your C program.

BTW, some other scripting languages & implementations have been specifically designed to be easily embedded in your C program, notably [Lua](http://lua.org/) & [GNU guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/)

Comment: You also explained it quite well, with a link to help out, thank you for that as well